# Best way to manipulate a conditional expression

Tags: java, regex

I have to manipulate an expression such as:

```
(Order.number.contains("A12") || Order.customer_name.startsWith("ACME"))
```

I need to get all elements such as `Order.number`, `Order.customer_name` and replace them with:

```
this["Order.number"].contains or this["Order.customer_name"].startWith
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in Java.

John

Comment: is this data coming from a DB.  If so try a where clause.

Comment: how can `this["Order.number"]` be a valid Java expression?

Comment: By parsing it, especially if they're arbitrary expressions. Otherwise with normal regex search and replace if they're highly regular.

Comment: @justhalf it's not supposed to be.  He/she wants to use Java to do a search/replace operation on something that isn't Java.

Comment: This is a drools expression

Comment: the pattern will always be "x.y "  or "x.y.contains(" or "x.y.equals("